# The intersection of two subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V be a vector space over an arbitrary field F and let W and Y be subspaces of V such that $W \cap Y = \{\vec{0}\}$. Also, suppose $\{w_1, \dots w_n \}$ is linearly independent in W and $\{y_1, \dots y_n \}$ is linearly independent in Y. To prove $\{w_1, \dots w_n, y_1,\dots y_n\}$ is linearly indpendent in V, can we conclude that this is linearly independent in V because the subspaces, W and Y, their intersection implies that these two subspaces are not multiples of one another and the fact that the vectors in both of them are both linearly independent means their combination is also linearly independent? or is more needed to prove if these vectors are linearly independent in V?

Comment: "Let $W$ and $Y$ be subspaces of V ... all the vectors in $W$ and all the vectors in $Y$ are linearly independent" - reading it literally, this is impossible.  Please try to be more clear about what you are asking.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I have edited the post to be more clear.

Comment: 1) in a nonzero vector space it will never happen that **all** vectors are linearly independent. You may however find maximal linearly independent sets, ie. bases. 2) What do you mean by vector spaces being multiple of one another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** use contraposition and the fact that both the $\{w_i\}$ and the $\{y_j\}$ are for  themselves linearly independent to deduce that $W \cap Y \neq 0$.